# Unsure how to create a MakeFIle

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I am having problems with creating a makefile for a project containing 3 c++ files.

While in the directory containing the files (tree.h, helperMethods.h, and main.cpp), I first use the command *emacs makefile.make*. Then, in emacs, I write the makefile as:

```
all: tree.h helperMethods.h main.cpp
[tab]g++ -std=c++0x -o project3 tree.h helperMethods.h main.cpp
```

I have verified manually that the command *g++ -std=c++0x -o project3 tree.h helperMethods.h main.cpp* does indeed compile the three files and make an executable that works at it should.

After this, I save the makefile, exit out of emacs, and attempt to run it.

First I used *make* but this returned:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

Then I tried using *make -f makefile.make* but this didn't work either and returned:

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

At this point, I'm unsure as to why the makefile wasn't constructed properly. I don't have very much experience with makefiles; I'm pretty sure that I have the commands in the body of the makefile correct but I didn't set it up properly when I wrote it.

If it is at all relevant, here are the 3 files:

tree.h:

```
#ifndef tree_h
#define tree_h
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class tree
{
public:
    tree<T> * parent;
    T element;
    vector<tree<T> > nodes;
    tree(const T& theElement)
    {
        element = theElement;
        nodes = vector<tree<T> >();
    }
    tree()
    {
        nodes = vector<tree<T> >();
    }
};

#endif
```

helperMethods.h

```
#ifndef helperMethods_h
#define helperMethods_h

#include "tree.h"

#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

string printName(tuple<string, string, string> myTuple){
    string ret = "";
    if(std::get<0>(myTuple).length() > 0)
        ret += get<0>(myTuple) + " ";
    if(std::get<1>(myTuple).length() > 0 || std::get<2>(myTuple).length() > 0)
        ret += "(";
    if(std::get<1>(myTuple).length() > 0)
        ret += get<1>(myTuple);
    if(std::get<1>(myTuple).length() > 0 && std::get<2>(myTuple).length() > 0)
        ret += ", ";
    if(std::get<2>(myTuple).length() > 0)
        ret += get<2>(myTuple);
    if(std::get<1>(myTuple).length() > 0 || std::get<2>(myTuple).length() > 0)
        ret += ")";
    return ret;
}

bool tupleContain(tuple<string, string, string> myTuple, string myString){
    return (std::get<0>(myTuple).compare(myString) == 0) || (std::get<1>(myTuple).compare(myString) == 0);
}

void findElement(tree<tuple<string, string, string> > myTree, string myString, bool* found, vector<int> *ret)
{
    if(tupleContain(myTree.element, myString))
        *found = true;
    if(! * found)
    {
        for(int counter = 0; counter < (int)myTree.nodes.size(); counter ++)
        {
            if(!* found)
            {
                (*ret).push_back(counter);
                findElement(myTree.nodes.at(counter), myString, found, ret);
                if(!* found)
                    (*ret).pop_back();
            }
        }
    }
}

void getLineage(tree<tuple<string, string, string> > myTree, string myString){
    bool dummyForFound = false;
    bool * found = & dummyForFound;
    vector<int> lineage = vector<int>();
    vector<int> * pointer = & lineage;
    findElement(myTree, myString, found, &lineage);
    if(lineage.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "Species not present" << endl;
        return;
    }
    vector<string> printString = vector<string>(lineage.size() + 1);
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > * currentNodePointer = & myTree;
    for(int counter = 0; counter <= (int) lineage.size(); counter ++)
    {
        string currentLine = "";
        for(int counter2 = 0; counter2 < 2*((int) lineage.size() - counter); counter2 ++)
            currentLine += ">";
        if(counter != lineage.size())
            currentLine += " ";
        tree<tuple<string, string, string> > currentNode = * currentNodePointer;
        currentLine += printName(currentNode.element);
        if(counter < (int) lineage.size())
        {
            int foo = lineage.at(counter);
            tree<tuple<string, string, string> > currentNodeDummy = currentNode.nodes.at(foo);
            *currentNodePointer = currentNodeDummy;
        }
        printString.at(counter) = currentLine;
    }
    for(int counter = 0; counter < (int) printString.size(); counter ++)
        cout << printString.at(printString.size() - counter - 1) << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

void getCommonLineage(tree<tuple<string, string, string> > myTree , string name1, string name2)
{
    bool dummyForFound = false;
    bool * found = & dummyForFound;
    vector<int> lineage1 = vector<int>();
    vector<int> * pointer1 = & lineage1;
    vector<int> lineage2 = vector<int>();
    vector<int> * pointer2 = & lineage2;
    findElement(myTree, name1, found, pointer1);
    * found = false;
    findElement(myTree, name2, found, pointer2);
    if(lineage2.size() == 0 || lineage1.size() == 0)
    {
        cout << "At least one species not present." << endl;
        return;
    }
    bool stillSame = lineage1.at(0) == lineage2.at(0);
    cout << "Level[0] Common Ancestor: ROOT (ROOT, ROOT)" << endl;
    tree<tuple<string, string, string>> * lastSharedNode = & myTree;
    int finalCounter = 0;
    for(int counter = 0; counter < (int) min(lineage1.size(), lineage2.size()) && stillSame; counter ++)
    {
        tree<tuple<string, string, string> > dummyNode = * lastSharedNode;
        tree<tuple<string, string, string> > currentNode = dummyNode.nodes.at(lineage1.at(counter));
        *lastSharedNode = currentNode;
        if(counter < (int) min(lineage1.size(), lineage2.size()) - 1 && lineage1.at(counter + 1) != lineage2.at(counter + 1))
            stillSame = false;
        tuple<string, string, string> currentElement = currentNode.element;
        cout << "Level[" << counter + 1 << "] Commont Ancestor: " << printName(currentElement) << endl;
        finalCounter ++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Ancestry unique to " << name1 << endl;
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > savedNode = *lastSharedNode;
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > * currentUnsharedNode = lastSharedNode;
    for(int counter = finalCounter; counter < (int) lineage1.size(); counter ++)
    {
        tree<tuple<string, string, string> > dummyNode = * currentUnsharedNode;
        tree<tuple<string, string, string> > currentNode = dummyNode.nodes.at(lineage1.at(counter));
        tuple<string, string, string> currentElement = currentNode.element;
        *currentUnsharedNode = currentNode;
        cout << "Level[" << counter + 1 << "] ";
        if(counter == lineage1.size() - 1)
            cout << "Species of interest: ";
        cout << printName(currentElement) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
    currentUnsharedNode = &savedNode;
    cout << "Ancestry unique to " << name2 << endl;
    for(int counter = finalCounter; counter < (int) lineage2.size(); counter ++)
    {
        tree<tuple<string, string, string> > dummyNode = * currentUnsharedNode;
        tree<tuple<string, string, string> > currentNode = dummyNode.nodes.at(lineage2.at(counter));
        tuple<string, string, string> currentElement = currentNode.element;
        *currentUnsharedNode = currentNode;
        cout << "Level[" << counter + 1 << "] ";
        if(counter == lineage2.size() - 1)
            cout << "Species of interest: ";
        cout << printName(currentElement) << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "rapidxml.h"
#include "tree.h"
#include "helperMethods.h"

#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <tuple>

using namespace rapidxml;

int main(int argc, const char * arv[]){
    tuple<string, string, string> human ("Human", "Homo sapiens", "Species");
    tuple<string, string, string> apes ("Apes", "", "");
    tuple<string, string, string> dogs ("Dogs", "", "");
    tuple<string, string, string> root ("Root", "", "");
    tuple<string, string, string> bears ("Bears", "", "");
    tuple<string, string, string> cat ("Cat", "", "");
    tuple<string, string, string> horse ("Horse", "", "");
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > myTree = tree<tuple<string, string, string>>(root);
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > b = tree<tuple<string, string, string>>(dogs);
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > c = tree<tuple<string, string, string>>(apes);
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > d = tree<tuple<string, string, string>>(bears);
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > e = tree<tuple<string, string, string>>(horse);
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > f = tree<tuple<string, string, string>>(human);
    tree<tuple<string, string, string> > h = tree<tuple<string, string, string>>(cat);
    d.nodes.push_back(f);
    e.nodes.push_back(h);
    b.nodes.push_back(d);
    b.nodes.push_back(e);
    myTree.nodes.push_back(b);
    myTree.nodes.push_back(c);
    cout << printName(myTree.nodes.at(0).element);

    cout << "Welcome to my Tree of Life program!" << endl << endl;

    int choice = 1;
    while(choice == 1 || choice == 2) {
        cout << "Please choose from the following options:" << endl;
        cout << "   1.Get the lineage of a species" << endl;
        cout << "   2.Get the commmon lineage of two species" << endl;
        cout << "   3.Exit program" << endl << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        cout << endl;
        if(choice == 1)
        {
            cout << "Please enter the name of the species of interest:" << endl;
            string name;
            cin >> name;
            cout << endl;
            getLineage(myTree, name);
        }
        if(choice == 2)
        {
            string name1, name2;
            cout << "Please enter the name of the first species: " << endl;
            cin >> name1;
            cout << "Please enter the name of the second species: " << endl;
            cin >> name2;
            getCommonLineage(myTree, name1, name2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: Posting the *entire* **Makefile** for problems you're having with makefiles is probably going to go a long way in assisting you to a solution. If the above is, in fact, your entire Makefile, I suggest you spend some serious time with [the gnu make online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/).

Comment: BTW, for complex `Makefile`-s, you might install then use `remake` instead of `make` (they are compatible), notably with the `-x` flag to `remake`

Comment: Another note about style: the general practice is to place definitions in .cpp files, and declarations (i.e. just function prototypes, class definitions, etc) in header files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makefiles are usually called `Makefile` (although `makefile` works, too) without any extension. If you use an extension (*not recommended*), you have to tell `make` the name of the makefile. That's tedious and unnecessary.

Second, you don't need to put header files in the compile command line, and you shouldn't do so. You use `#include` lines in your file to specify the header files. So your compile command might look like this:

```
g++ -std=c++0x -o project3 main.cpp
```

Now, in that command:

- `main.cpp` is the *source*
- `project3` is the *target* (i.e., the file which will be created.)

Also:

- `tree.h` and `helperMethods.h` are needed for the compile to work; the compilation *depends* on this files. (You know that, but they don't show up in the command-line so its not obvious.) Furthermore, if they change, you have to recompile your file.

A makefile explains how to make a *target* from its *sources*, and also lists the *dependencies* of the *target*. (Technically, make doesn't distinguish between *sources* and *dependencies*; it considers both of them *prerequisites*. But it's convenient to recognize the difference.)

So for the above command, the entire make recipe might look like this:

```
project3: main.cpp tree.h helperMethods.h 
        g++ -std=c++0x -o project3 main.cpp
```

Normally, we don't use filenames like `main.cpp`; rather, we'd call the main file for project3 `project3.cpp`, just as the target (output) file is `project3`. In fact, if you did that, and you didn't have any other dependencies (header files), you could type:

```
make project3
```

*without a makefile at all*, and `make` would come up with the command:

```
g++ -o project3 project3.cpp
```

In this case, that command would be wrong because it doesn't specify the correct C++ standard. But it often works, and it's a good reason to name your targets and sources with the same basename.

One more thing: your file `tree.h` is a header-only library, which is fine. But `helperMethods.h` is only pretending to be a header file. It's really a complete implementation. You should fix that.

Also, it's *really* a bad idea to put `using namespace std` in a header file. Header files should explicitly use the `std::` namespace prefix on everything which needs it. It's generally not recommended to use `using namespace std` anywhere, but it's particularly bad in header files because it silently pollutes the default namespace of any file which includes the header. This can lead to very obscure bugs, or compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

School project, eh?  `project3` seems an awful arbitrary name for something you're working on yourself.

You don't need to include .h files in your makefile processing because, strictly speaking, they never need to be compiled independently.  Your makefile would need a rule for building main.o out of main.cpp, and then a rule for building an executable out of main.o.  The header files should be added as dependencies of main.o, so that if either of them change, `make` will know to rebuild from there.

Basically, it will need to look something like this:

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458126/unsure-how-to-create-a-makefile
all: project3

clean:
    -rm main.o project3

project3: main.o
    g++ -std=c++0x -o project3 main.o

main.o: main.cpp tree.h helperMethods.h
    g++ -std=c++0x -c main.cpp
```

Someone else may produce a dramatically different, but equally valid, makefile for this purpose.  There's a degree of freedom to the process.

What you have here is a rule to build the whole thing (keeping in mind that if no target is provided, the first one in the makefile is automatically chosen), rules to clean up any intermediate files, a rule to build the executable from the object files, and a rule to build the object file from the source files.  This approach doesn't scale very well; it would be unpleasant to manage by hand all of the dependencies for larger, more complex makefiles, but in this very simple case it's fine.